# d3 call zoom on graph with mouseover on items

Tags: d3.js

I have call zoom attached to my graph and it works fine.

When I attach a mouseover event to an item ( a rectangle) in the chart the mouseover fires but the zoom isn't called.

I'm trying to have a mouse-rollover make a tooltip appear and 'mouse-click and drag' make the chart pan on the y-axis only.

Is there an easy way to get these to work together or should I customize the events as in this example?

http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434

```
bar = g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(currentData)
            .enter().append('rect')
            .attr("class", "horizontal bar")
            .attr("x", 0)

        .attr("height", ordinalScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {
            return ordinalScale(d.key);
        })
            .attr("width", 0)
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {

            tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);


            tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 80) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
                .append('p')
                .text(d.key)
                .attr('class', 'tootip-key')
                .append('p')
                .text(d.value)
                .attr('class', 'tooltip-value');

            tooltip.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", 0.9);

        })

            .on("mouseout", function(d) {

            tooltip.remove();


        });
```

and the zoom behavior is attached like so.

```
g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", zoom));
```

thanks!

Comment: So... you're trying to call the zoom behaviour from the mouseover event? Or do you want a mouseover event and then when you click on it zoom? What exactly are you trying to do and what is your code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way to get a tooltip is to append an `svg:title` element to the elements that you want to have a tooltip. The rest will be taken care of by the browser. If you need something fancier, have a look at [tipsy](https://github.com/bigmlcom/tipsy).

To limit panning to the y axis, simply ignore the translation for the `x` value in your handler function (`zoom` in your case).